# SET default_parallel 1; statement not working on pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I  am new to pig and as per my understanding `SET default_parallel 1` statement should produce one output file as it will use one reducer. But when I am using this command on below script its giving me 2 o/p files.

```
SET default_parallel 1;
A = LOAD 'hdfs:/pigfldr/union1' using PigStorage(' ') AS (sln:int);
B = LOAD 'hdfs:/pigfldr/union2' using PigStorage(' ') AS (sln:int);
C = UNION A, B;

STORE C INTO 'hdfs:/pigfldr/unionfres';
```

Comment: It also depends on your hdfs blocs size (among other parameters), but why do you want to have exactly 1 output file ? I guess you'll still have the "_succes" file if nothing went wrong.

Comment: I want to merge this two file. I want records of file A first and then B in one file.

Comment: It is quite common that MapReduce process give more than one output file. If you want to use those results in your local file system into one file use hadoop fs -get merge https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#getmerge, if you want to stay in HDFS use output/path/*.

Answer (score 4):

Even me to new to pig. But as per my knowledge **"SET default_parallel 1;"(parallel features) will work on reducer only, Not on mapper.**
So only you are getting two files.
Because Union function using only mapper not reducer in your case.
You can see your output file named as part-m-00000 and part-m-00001, that m refers the mapper output file. Its not reducer output file if it reducer output file means it will be like part-r-0000*

Comment: you are correct, but I want to output both the result of the union to one file.